# Identifying the row that contains characters in a column of a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that in one of the columns, the rows contain numbers and characters and I need to identify in which rows are the characters.

Here is the data.frame

```
 Time..sec. R1.R1
1       0.54  0.95
2       1.50  0.94
3       2.46  0.95
4       3.42  "3mM + R568"
5       4.37  0.95
6       5.33  0.95
```

Comment: can you provide that dataframe?

Comment: it is very simple it has two columns first column all numbers and second column all numbers except for three rows of characters that are my "label" and I need to identify them. But it treats all data as the same type of object and I can not manage to do it. I do not know hot to provide the data frame (I am new here)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
df <- read.table(text = " Time..sec. R1.R1
1       0.54  0.95
2       1.50  0.94
3       2.46  0.95
4       3.42  '3mM + R568'
5       4.37  0.95
6       5.33  0.95")


which(is.na(as.numeric(as.character(df[, 2]))))
```

Comment: it does not work this is the message: integer(0). Because it takes data[,2] as factor not as a numeric ...

Comment: seems like it the column got converted to a factor, you would need to convert to character first

Comment: check out the updated example using your data sample